# Determining whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac n{n+1}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have this series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac n{n+1}$$ I have to determine if this series converges. If I do the ratio test, I get:

$$L = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{\left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)}{\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)}\right| = 1$$ 
And if this test is equal to $1$, then it seems like I have to perform another kind of test, but I don't know what. What should I do?

Comment: What is the very first necessary criterion for the convergence of a series that one hears of? Is that satisfied here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The series diverges. What is a test we can use to test divergence?

In general, with these series questions you usually want to have an idea of whether it converges or diverges and then use tests to confirm your notion. In this case, you see that each term in the sequence stays around $1$, so you would think it diverges since you're just adding $1$ over and over again. So you would want to use a test to prove that. Furthermore, in describing why it diverges (or converges), you should have a good idea of what test to use already.

Answer (score 5):

The general term of the series $\frac n{n+1}$ doesn't converge to $0$ then the series is divergent.